# CSS3 - Translating an element across the screen in steps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, css-animations

I need to translate an element across the screen in steps of say 50px. Upon every click, the element moves 50px to the right, lets say.

How do i correct the following code?

http://jsfiddle.net/vujMV/13/

Here it jumps 50px each time and then translates 50px, a total of 100px per click. I need the movement to be hardware accelerated (since it is to be deployed on a mobile platform) and hence I would need to use translate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment out the final two lines. Those are what cause the initial 50px jump:

```
//left += 50;
//move.style.left = left+"px";
```

**Edit**
To make it work each time you click it, you need to change the translate3d property relative to the current one, rather than the `.offset` property since that is no longer changing once you comment out the above lines.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vujMV/16/